# style problem when adding entity with RAD power tools

Tags: aspnetzero

[image: style problem]

all run ok, but when add new view .. it show like the image

i did use yarn & npm run create-bundles.
I did try with modal or without modal.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in AspNetZeroRadTool/config.json
i didnt use the correct "ApplicationAreaName": "App",

in my case "App"

this needs to be the same area name. ()
this this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQGuB.png)

then the problem goes away